# Sorting DefaultListModel

Tags: java, defaultlistmodel

I would like to sort my `DefaultListModel` and have it to fire the contents changed event, but I'm stuck with it, and don't understand how can I call its fireContentsChanged method.  I see that if my model extends `AbstractListModel` I can directly call the fireContentsChanged after the sorting, but in the way I did my class with the DefaultListModel, I can't call its fireContentsChanged cause it has protected access.  Do I have to extends `AbstractListModel`
 or is there a way to call the `DefaultListModel` fireContentsChanged ?

```
public class DefaultDataModel implements DataModel 
{
  private DefaultListModel<Data> dataModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
  @Override
  public void addElement(Data data) {
    dataModel.addElement(data);
  }
  @Override
  public int getSize() {
    return dataModel.getSize();
  }
  @Override
  public Data getElementAt(int idx) {
    return dataModel.getElementAt(idx);
  }
  @Override
  public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
    dataModel.addListDataListener(l);
  }
  @Override
  public int indexOf(Data data) {
    return dataModel.indexOf(data);
  }
  @Override
  public List<Data> getAllData() {
    return Collections.list(dataModel.elements());
  }
  @Override
  public void sort() {
    Collections.sort(getAllData());
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you want to invoke "fireContentsChanged" method after sorting all elements, or after each change of position of items during sorting?

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to do it after each change of position.  I think in my case I just need to call the fireContentsChanged after all elements are sorted, but I wouldn't mind having a look at how to do it after each change of items position.

Comment: I know this is old, but note that DefaultDataModel#sort() method is not going to modify the order of the elements of the DefaultDataModel or of its delegate DefaultListModel.

It's going to sort the List that is constructed by #getAllData() which will then be thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do it in the sort method I have to call the contentsChanged method from the dataModel listeners list.

```
@Override
public void sort() {
    Collections.sort(getAllData());
    ListDataListener[] listeners = dataModel.getListDataListeners();
    for(ListDataListener listener : listener) {
        listener.contentsChanged(dataModel, ListDataEvent.CONTENTS_CHANGED, 0, getSize());
    }
}
```